# bind.() function only sends last argument

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am working on a chat program in python using tkinter and I want to enable the user to click on a name and open a chat in a new tkinter window, but when I click on the names only the last name gets passed through.

I originally used a while loop to loop through the different users in the database.

In hope that the bug would be fixed I switched to a for loop but nothing changed.

This is my current code:

```
def openchat(event):
root= Tk()
root.title(contactname)
print("everything binds to this")
print("contactname: %s" % contactname)


def contacts():

c.execute("SELECT contact_id FROM contacts WHERE user_id = ?", (session_id[0], ))
row = c.fetchall();

print("prints contact id: %s" % row, "\n")
rowlength = len(row)
x = 0
print(row[x][0])

#while x < rowlength:
for i in row:
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (row[x][0], ))
    row2 = c.fetchone();
    print("('contact_id', 'contactname', 'password', 'chat_id')")
    print(row2)
    contactname[0] = row2[1]
    print("contactname: %s" % contactname, "x: %s" % x, "\n")
    contactframe = Frame(leftframe, bg="#00A098", highlightthickness=2.5, highlightbackground="Black")
    contactframe.pack(side = TOP, fill=X)
    contactframe.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: openchat(contactname))
    n = Label(contactframe, text=contactname, fg="Black", bg='#00A098')
    n.config(font=("Ariel", 20))
    n.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: openchat(contactname))
    n.pack()
    x+=1
```

This is the terminal output I get when running the program:

```
contact function: 

prints contact id: [('2',), ('3',), ('4',)] 

2
('contact_id', 'contactname', 'password', 'chat_id')
('2', 'brian', 'brian', '2')
contactname: ['brian'] x: 0 

('contact_id', 'contactname', 'password', 'chat_id')
('3', 'abdi', 'abdi', '3')
contactname: ['abdi'] x: 1 

('contact_id', 'contactname', 'password', 'chat_id')
('4', 'john', 'john', '4')
contactname: ['john'] x: 2
```

All of the above works perfectly as expected but this is where I mess up. Everything binds to the last contact, John

```
contactname: ['john']
contactname: ['john']
contactname: ['john']
```

But it should display something like this:

```
contactname: ['brian']
contactname: ['abdi']
contactname: ['john']
```

My current theory is that the bind function only runs when I click the button and therefore only outputs the last contact name, I could be wrong though.

It would be highly appreciated if someone could show me where I did something wrong or point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

=============

**I figured out a solution that worked for me, here is my final code incase anyone else has a similar problem:**

```
def openchat(i):
  c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (i, ))
  row = c.fetchall();
  contactname = row[0][1]
  root= Tk()
  root.title(contactname)
  print("contactname: %s" % contactname)


def contacts(self):

  c.execute("SELECT contact_id FROM contacts WHERE user_id = ?", (session_id[0], ))
  row = c.fetchall();

  print("prints contact id: %s" % row, "\n")
  rowlength = len(row)
  minrow = min(row)
  maxrow = max(row)
  minrow2 = minrow[0]
  maxrow2 = maxrow[0]
  minrow2 = int(minrow2)
  maxrow2 = int(maxrow2)
  x = 0
  print(row[x][0])

  for i in range(minrow2,maxrow2+1):

      self.contact_id = i
      c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (row[x][0], ))
      row2 = c.fetchone();
      print(row2)
      contactname[0] = row2[1]
      print("contactname: %s" % contactname, "x: %s" % x, "\n")
      contactframe = Frame(leftframe, bg="#00A098", highlightthickness=2.5, highlightbackground="Black")
      contactframe.pack(side = TOP, fill=X)
      n = Button(contactframe, text=contactname, fg="Black", bg='#00A098', command = lambda i=i: openchat(i))
      #n.config(font=("Ariel", 20))
      n.pack()
      x+=1
```

Comment: Please show what you've done to research this problem. There are many questions on this site related to creating commands or bindings or widgets in a loop.

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: Simplify your approach to: `n.bind("<Button-1>", openchat)` and `def openchat(event): print("event from {}".format(event.widget['text']))`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @BryanOakley, How do I show what I've researched? (First time I've posted on stack overflow..). I have researched a lot on google and also here on different posts but what I've seen mostly are problems with displaying data from a database, where my problem is sending the right information forward to another function. Hope this clarifies a little.

Comment: Thanks for the code @stovfl, I've implemented the code you gave me but I receive an error.

Here is what I've tried:

`print("everything binds to this {}".format(event.widget[contactname]))`

but received the error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

and I also tried this:

`print("everything binds to this {}".format(event.widget[contactname[0]]))`

where I got the error: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-john"

Comment: @pbb.business: **Why**, `contactname`? The attribute of a `Label` is `text`.

Comment: @stovfl, when I use `text` I get this error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-text"`

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**: when I use `'text'` I get this error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-text"`

The following works for me:

```py
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        n = tk.Label(self, text='test', fg="Black", bg='#00A098')
        n.config(font=("Ariel", 20))
        n.bind("<Button-1>", self.openchat)
        n.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def openchat(self, event):
        print("event from {}".format(type(event.widget))
        # >>> event from <class 'tkinter.Label'>
        print("event from {}".format(event.widget['text']))
        # >>> event from test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: When I use this method I still get the error `return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-text"`, however if I remove event.widget the program executes and returns this: `contactname: ['john']
event from test`. Do you have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @pbb.business: Have your run my example standalone as it is?

Comment: yes and it returns `event from <class 'tkinter.Label'>` `event from test` which I assume is the intended output. Do you by any chance know if your code works if you automatically pull data from a list or database as I did above?

Comment: @pbb.business: know if your code works ... pull data ... I did above? Yes, but it's to broad for SO, setup a [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com), there I can go supporting you, step by step.